# "Display 2 isn't active" error when trying to connect a second screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, usb-c, thunderbolt

I'm trying to connect a second screen, however, Windows 11 seems to recognize the screen, but says it's "not active" hence there is no output on the display. The display itself just wakes up for a second and then says it's going into energy-saving mode.

My display is a Dell U2711 and it's connected via a Displayport to USB-C cable to my notebook.
Notebook is a Dell Precision 3571 which has an integrated graphics card (Intel Iris Xe Graphics) as well as a dedicated one (Nvidia RTX A1000). From my understanding it uses the Intel graphics card for displaying non 3D stuff.
I'm using [this cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DisplayPort-uni-Compatible-MacBook-Surface/dp/B075V27G2R/ref=sr_1_1?crid=U3UO3ZW68DDD&keywords=uni%20USB%20C%20Displayport%20Kabel%20%284K%4060Hz%2C%202K%40165Hz%29%2C%20Typ%20C%20Thunderbolt%203%2F4%20auf%20DP%20Kabel%20unterst%C3%BCtzt%20MST%2C%20Freesync.1.8m%20Nylonkabel%20%26%20Aluminiumgeh%C3%A4use.%20F%C3%BCr%20MacBook%20Pro%2FAir%2C%20iPad%20Pro%202022%2F2021%20M1%2F2%2C%20XPS%20usw.&qid=1677258719&sprefix=uni%20usb%20c%20displayport%20kabel%204k%2060hz%202k%20165hz%20typ%20c%20thunderbolt%203%2F4%20auf%20dp%20kabel%20unterst%C3%BCtzt%20mst%20freesync.1.8m%20nylonkabel%20%26%20aluminiumgeh%C3%A4use.%20f%C3%BCr%20macbook%20pro%2Fair%20ipad%20pro%202022%2F2021%20m1%2F2%20xps%20usw.%20%2Caps%2C297&sr=8-1)
I already tried another monitor using the same cable and it yields the same results. So I'm really suspecting some driver issue, maybe with the thunderbolt ports?

Everything works over HDMI. I tried 2 different cables, which had no effect. And I tried an alternative notebook (older Dell) which worked.

I had this problem some weeks ago, and a restart fixed it. Today I installed a directx update and windows update and since the last restart I got confronted with this problem again.

Any hints on solving this problem? I'm happy to provide more details (does dxdiag output help?).

This is how it looks like in the intel driver:
[image]

I can try to activate it via the 3 dots but it doesn't work.

And this is in the display settings of Windows:
[image]

Device manager shows:
[image]

If I connect the same monitor via HDMI as well, it shows the display twice. I can't really tell any difference between the 2 when I look at their properties.
[image]

Display Adapters:
[image]

Comment: What is the cable used for the monitor? You may find troubleshooting tips [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-your-second-monitor-not-being-detected-windows-10).

Comment: Thank you! Added the link to the cable. I found does troubleshooting tips already, but unfortunately they were of no help.

Comment: Strange documentation : "no adapter or driver/software required". Seems to promise that the cable contains an in-built display adapter. Connect the cable and add a screenshot to Device Manager > Display adapters.

Comment: Added a screenshot. It's really weird because Windows recognizes the display, but I have no idea what "inactive" means in this case. And also it "connects" to the display because it wakes up the monitor. It's just going back to energysaving right away.

Comment: I asked for Display adapters, not Monitors.

Comment: Sorry, lost in translation :D Added the screenshot.

Comment: This is a very old monitor. Its [last driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ae/product-support/product/dell-u2711/drivers) dates from 2013 and goes up to Windows 8, so is a doubtful option (but you could try). It may not be compatible with the Displayport driver of Windows 11, while an older standard like HDMI works fine.

Comment: I will try that, thank you. I just don't understand why it did work for some weeks. 
I just tested the same setup with another monitor (more recent Asus PB279) and it yields the same results.

Comment: If you get the same thing with a more recent monitor, my analysis might be incorrect. I don't understand why it's not using the NVIDIA card - which driver is used for the NVIDIA?

Comment: It works! I changed the configuration in the nvidia control panel to always use the nvidia card - I've done that in the past. But now I restarted afterwards. And the second monitor works. Although it's still showing that it's connected with the Intel Iris Xe graphics card... 
I will look a bit more into it and update an answer tomorrow. 
Thank you very much for your help and that precious last hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird problems require weird solutions...
I followed [this](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/de-at/000190229/how-to-set-nvidia-video-as-the-default-with-computers-that-have-integrated-and-discrete-video-cards?lang=en) guide and did a restart after advising to always take the nvidia card. And then it just worked again. Although it still shows that the Intel Iris Xe Graphics card is driving the 2 displays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, but my laptop do not have the second video adapter. In my case when I connected a third monitor over hdmi then my second monitor, that was connected over usb type-c, stopped working as monitor and continued working as touch input only.

Solution that worked for me:

Open `Intel Graphics Command Center` application, right click on grayed display and enable it.